# How to use a query parameter to have the server delete the API call cache (django, DRF)

Tags: django, caching, memcached, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework and DRF-extensions (http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#how-key-constructor-works).

I have an API call /user/:id/products, which provides the full list of products that a user has access to.  Because it's an expensive query, I'm caching it based on method id, format, language, user, and retrieval SQL query.

I have another API call /pay which handles all of our payments.  The product ids are POST arguments to that API call.

After a user pays, immediately it directs them to the product page--but since the product query is cached, it still displays the old list of products, not the updated list with the new products they just purchased.  I know about the `cache.delete` method, but getting the key from `/pay` is difficult since it's a completely different API call.

What I would like to do is add a parameter `force_refresh` to the `/user/:id/products` API call, that, if present, calculates the hash key as if the `force_refresh` parameter weren't present and then clears the cache for that key.  However, I can't find the right place in `KeyConstructor` within drf-extension's caching framework to stick this in. **What is the best way for me to let the server know to delete the cache for this query?**

Answer (score 2):

Example for using DRF-extensions caching with all GET params as key hash on ReadOnlyModelViewSet.

Define your key constructor (key hash):

```
from rest_framework_extensions.key_constructor.constructors import DefaultKeyConstructor
from rest_framework_extensions.key_constructor.bits import QueryParamsKeyBit

class QueryParamsKeyConstructor(DefaultKeyConstructor):
    all_query_params = QueryParamsKeyBit('*')  # Don't change, * is default on drf-extension dev version only
```

And your view:

```
class UserViewSet(ListCacheResponseMixin, viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    list_cache_key_func = QueryParamsKeyConstructor()
```

set DRF-extensions and django caching settings in settings.py, for example:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "redis_cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0"
    }
}

REST_FRAMEWORK_EXTENSIONS = {
'DEFAULT_CACHE_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT': 20
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> What I would like to do is add a parameter force_refresh to the /user/:id/products API call

I don't think it's a good idea. What if your client made `/pay` request and then used his own routing to `/user/:id/products` ? With `force_refresh` attribute you are adding state for request and it is not idempotent anymore.

If you have high read rate and low write rate I would suggest you to look at creation of [custom key bit](http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#custom-key-bit) with global cached invalidation, based on post save signals.

If you want to make cache invalidation more specific I would suggest you to denormalize your User model. For example:

```
class User(UserBaseModel):
    ...
    products_updated_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

You should update `products_updated_date` every time you make payments:

```
class UserViewSet(CacheResponseMixin, ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    ...
    @action('pay')
    def pay(self):
        ...
        self.request.user.products_updated_date = now()
        self.request.user.save()
        ...
```

And finally you should create custom key bit with users's `products_updated_date` field usage:

```
from rest_framework_extensions.key_constructor.bits import (
    KeyBitBase
)

class UserProductsUpdatedKeyBit(KeyBitBase):
    def get_data(self, **kwargs):
        request = kwargs['request']
        if (hasattr(request, 'user') and 
            request.user and 
            request.user.is_authenticated()):
            return request.user.products_updated_date
```

You can add `UserProductsUpdatedKeyBit` to your key constructor class for `/user/:id/products` routing.